# Ошибка Stack around the variable 'X' was corrupted

Tags: c++

Выдаёт Stack around the variable 'X' was corrupted.(Ну и Y соответственно)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;
void proc(int M[], int w, int e) {
    int col = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < w; i++) {
        for (int a = 0; a < e; a++) {
            if (M[i*w+a] >= 0 && M[i*w+a] <= 1) {
                col++;
            }
        }
    }
    cout << col << "\n";
}

void randF(int M[], int w, int e) {
    for (int i = 0; i < w; i++) {
        for (int a = 0; a < e; a++) {
            M[i*w+a] = rand() % 10 - 5;
            cout <<setw(3)<< M[i*w+a];
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
    cout << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    const int x1 = 10;
    const int x2 = 15;
    const int y1 = 20;
    const int y2 = 12;
    int X[x2][x1];
    int Y[y2][y1];
    randF(&X[0][0], x2, x1);
    randF(&Y[0][0], y2, y1);
    proc(&X[0][0], x2, x1);
    proc(&Y[0][0], y2, y1);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Неправильно преобразуете двухмерный индекс в одномерный.

Вместо `M[i*w+a]` нужно делать `M[i*e+a]`.

Comment: оу ... точно, спасибо